# Intervalo de datas formatadas - retorno de between

Tags: mysql, query, data

Estou fazendo um select de um intervalo de datas, porém, quando o faço formatado está retornando dados que não deveria retornar, no caso, meses a mais e meses a menos... Segue intervalo e query.

```
SELECT
    id, DATE_FORMAT( created_at,'%d/%m/%Y %H:%i:%s' ) as created_at
FROM
    use_card 
WHERE
    DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i:%s') BETWEEN "01/05/2019 00:00:00" 
    AND "13/06/2019 18:05:32" 
ORDER BY
    DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i:%s') ASC

id  created_at
15  02/04/2019 09:42:47
13  02/05/2019 09:40:50
17  02/05/2019 09:43:41
80  03/06/2019 19:48:13
117 04/06/2019 07:42:42
116 04/06/2019 08:20:21
118 04/06/2019 08:45:24
122 06/02/2019 11:58:42
119 06/06/2019 11:57:26
120 06/06/2019 11:57:57
121 06/06/2019 11:58:33
123 06/06/2019 18:07:20
124 06/06/2019 18:08:36
125 06/06/2019 19:27:38
126 06/06/2019 22:09:15
25  07/05/2019 10:07:26
27  07/05/2019 10:17:17
28  07/05/2019 10:19:08
29  07/05/2019 10:45:38
26  07/07/2019 10:14:03
57  09/05/2019 09:40:20
```

Caso alguém possa ajudar, agradeço.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acontece que a função `DATE_FORMAT` retorna uma string. Não use esta função para fazer filtro ou ordenação, não faz sentido algo assim.

O select deveria ser

```
SELECT
    id, DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i:%s') as created_at
FROM
    use_card 
WHERE
   created_at BETWEEN "2019/05/01 00:00:00" AND "2019/06/13 18:05:32" 
ORDER BY
    created_at ASC
```

<sup>[**Veja funcionando no DBFiddle**](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/eRTDNbvVsGBHRqLqNM1CyM/0)</sup>

Comment: Se houver qualquer possibilidade de má interpretação das datas limites fornecidas utilize BETWEEN CAST("01/05/2019 00:00:00" AS DATETIME)  AND CAST("13/06/2019 18:05:32" AS DATETIME). Note que a resposta de LINQ elimina eventuais problemas de interpretação da data ao utilizar o formato ISO.